# How to set user and group permissions properly for different groups?

Tags: server, permissions, user-management

On a Ubuntu 20.04 server i have two drives in /media.

1. /media/data (internal drive)
2. /media/network_drive (network drive)

I have several user groups (group1, ..., groupN). For each group there should be a folder on /media/data (01_group1, ..., N_groupN). Additional, group1 (and only group1) should have accesss to /media/network_drive. Others (not in those groups) should not have access to both drives at all.

On /media/data, every user should have read, write, execute permissions in the folders which are belonging to the group(s) he is in. Furthermore if a user creates a file in one of those folders, the group of this file should automatically be the group of the folder. Is this the right way? As I understand, a user named john is in primary group john, and if he creates a file, this file has user john and group john, and is therefore not rwx for others, if permissions are 770 for example.

My attempt would be:
Create a parent group groupAll for all users in group1, ..., groupN.

```
sudo chgrp groupAll /media/data
sudo chgrp -R group1 /media/data/group1
...
sudo chgrp -R groupN /media/data/groupN
sudo chmod -R 770 /media/data
sudo chgrp -R group1 /media/network_drive
sudo chmod -R 770 /media/network_drive
```

What do i have to do additionally, that if user john, which is in group1, group3 and groupAll

1. creates a file in group1, the file automatically belongs to group group1
2. creates a file in group3, the file automatically belongs to group group3  ?

My questions are:

1. Are the permissions i have given to the mounting points /media/data and /media/network_drive correct?
2. What are the options i have to pass in the /etc/fstab to those drives?
3. Do i need ACL for this, or is this possible with standard unix user permissions?
4. What are the SetUID and SetGID Bits?

Furthermore:
What is the difference between the -R option and this here:

```
find /folder/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /folder/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

With the second one, you can differ between files and folders, is this the only difference?

Thanks in advance for your answers!